# Turn-on and turn-off switching energy

Tags: mosfet, switching-losses

Is it possible to calculate the turn-on and turn-off energy of SiC-MOSFETs with datasheet parameters? The method with ½ * U * I * tr (or tf) cannot be used here. Let us take the C2M0080120D from Cree as an example. In its datasheet, it is stated that the turn-on energy at Vds = 800 V and Id = 20 is 265µJ. With a Si-MOSFET it is relatively easy to determine the switching energy for an inductive load:

E(on) = 0.5 * tr * Vds_max * Id_max

That would be 160µJ for the C2M0080120D. Therefore, I cannot use this equation to calculate the turn-on energy.

Comment: What do you mean by turn on and turn off energy? Do you mean switching losses?

Comment: The switching energy you give is an approximation assuming that V_gs is approximately linear with time during the rise time. This is not in general true; in particular, look up the term "Miller plateau".

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes and no, the switching losses are the energy multiplied with the switching frequency (Psw = E(on) * fs).

Comment: @Hearth : I know that the Miller plateau is not constant for SiC-MOSFETs. The question is whether it is still possible to determine the turn-on and turn-off energy.

Comment: The equation you give provides a lower bound. I don't think there's any easier way to find a more precise value than just simulating it with a proper device model, or measuring it with a real device.

Comment: I start to think that it is only possible to calculate the losses with an analytical model. @Hearth, of course, you are absolutely right, the equation is only an approximation. But I hoped it would be more accurate.

Comment: Did you look at figures 23-26 of the [datasheet](https://www.wolfspeed.com/media/downloads/167/C2M0080120D.pdf)? They might give you useful values to make approximations with.